# Broken link in my reactjs hosted from netlify

Tags: html, css, reactjs, netlify

I recently hosted in Netlify through github and my website which is rendered from reactjs. My website link is https://realhomes.netlify.com/ . So when i try to reload my website from other page except from home(index page) it shows broken link and i don't know how to fix it. Please help.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It looks like you're using `react-router` within your site to route between different pages. If that's the case, you'll need to tell Netlify to serve the `index.html` file for everything, not just the root of the site.

From [this netlify blog post](https://www.netlify.com/blog/2016/07/22/deploy-react-apps-in-less-than-30-seconds/)

> If you choose to use something for routing (like React Router for example), you will need to set up a redirect and rewrite rule for the single page app.

Try adding `/*    /index.html   200` to a `_redirects` file in your publish directory or the following to your `netlify.toml`.

```
[[redirects]]
  from = "/*"
  to = "/index.html"
  status = 200
```

[Read the docs here](https://docs.netlify.com/routing/redirects/#syntax-for-the-redirects-file)

Comment: Thanks for the answer but should i make a file name netlify.toml and put the code below or what should i do?
[link](https://github.com/NutanPanta/Real-Homes),this is my githublink to the file . Can you please tell me where to put and how to put.

Comment: Yes, probably. Take a look at the documentation - https://docs.netlify.com/configure-builds/file-based-configuration/#sample-file
I haven't personally used netlify, but their documentation is pretty good.

Answer (score 1):

In the public folder create `_redirects` file and add `/* /index.html  200`, now your app will not crash on refresh.

Answer (score 0):

If someone wants to know how the netlify.toml file looks like you can find it in my 
github repository in [Link Here](https://github.com/NutanPanta/Real-Homes) and it works.

Answer (score 0):

create file: _redirects

content: /* /index.html 200

*if you are deploying a build folder then make sure to follow the steps after the build is successful make a file below the static folder in the build

[image: a short example]